# fat-fs(mmcblk0p1): volume was not properly unmountd.some data may be corrupt. please run fsck

Tags: linux

My customized system has this alarm when it starts, which means that I did not uninstall partition `mmcblk0p1` when shutting down. How can I modify `/etc/fstab` to automatically uninstall it when a power outage occurs?

Printing of a portion of `dmesg`：

```
...
    [    6.488912] CAN device driver interface
    [    6.502179] f81604_probe: Fintek F81604 driver version: v1.19
    [    6.550910] f81604 1-8:1.0: Channel #0 registered as can0
    [    6.597869] f81604_is_hw_disable: ch: 1, i: 100, r: 100
    [    6.597872] f81604 1-8:1.0: f81604_probe: channel 1 is h/w diabled
    [    6.597905] usbcore: registered new interface driver f81604
    [    6.613718] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): recovery complete
    [    6.614116] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem fbc7620b-3aec-4ad5-8f01-b1d8f2006a4c r/w with ordered data mode. Quota mode: none.
    [    6.615305] FAT-fs (mmcblk0p1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
    [    6.637649] i2c i2c-0: ioctl, cmd=0x705, arg=0x7ffc39b81308
    [    6.637663] i2c i2c-0: ioctl, cmd=0x703, arg=0x74
    [    6.637667] i2c i2c-0: ioctl, cmd=0x720, arg=0x7ffc39b812d0
...
```

blkid:

```
root@dobot:~# blkid
/dev/mmcblk0p3: UUID="2692a861-c28c-4127-a037-dd1756b28da0" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mmcblk0p2: UUID="fbc7620b-3aec-4ad5-8f01-b1d8f2006a4c" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mmcblk0p1: UUID="C377-C6E3" TYPE="vfat"
```

/etc/fstab:

```
root@dobot:~# cat /etc/fstab
#device          mount-point            type           options     dump   fsck order
UUID=2692a861-c28c-4127-a037-dd1756b28da0   /                      ext4           defaults    0          1
UUID=fbc7620b-3aec-4ad5-8f01-b1d8f2006a4c   /boot                  ext4           defaults    0          1
UUID=C377-C6E3   /boot/efi              vfat           umask=0077  0          0
proc             /proc                  proc           defaults    0          0
sysfs            /sys                   sysfs          defaults    0          0
tmpfs            /tmp                   tmpfs          defaults    0          0
tmpfs            /var                   tmpfs          defaults    0          0
debugfs          /sys/kernel/debug      debugfs        default     0          0
mdev             /dev                   ramfs          defaults    0          0
devpts           /dev/pts               devpts         defaults    0          0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are no devices on the market which could predict **all** power outages before they actually happen without fail, the typical way to fix this for sure is with an Uninterruptible Power Supply (UPS for short).

When external power fails, the UPS would alert the system, and the system could then shut down in a controlled manner before UPS's batteries run down.

If you dont want such a solution, then there is a workaround that won't provide complete protection, but might be enough:

`/boot/efi` is only needed in two situations:

- when booting (read-only access is sufficient)
- when updating the bootloader (read-write access required)

If you can add functionality to your system update mechanism to mount `/boot/efi` whenever a bootloader update is being installed, and unmount it afterwards, you could leave it unmounted in normal use (just add a `noauto` mount option for it in `/etc/fstab`).

If you are using a package manager to deliver updates to your customized system, you could just add a pre-install script to your bootloader package that tests for `/boot/efi` being mounted, and if not, mounting it and setting a flag to remember that it did so; and a post-install script to unmount it again if the flag was set by the pre-install script.

If you have something like `grub.cfg` located within `/boot/efi`, you might also have to patch `grub2-mkconfig` or similar boot configuration update tools to automatically mount & unmount `/boot/efi` if required.

That should drastically minimize the time the `/boot/efi` filesystem needs to be mounted and writeable, and so stop this error from occurring unless power is lost during an update of the bootloader or its configuration. That should be extremely rare.

You might also want to change the `fsck order` number field in `/etc/fstab` from 0 to 2 for `/boot/efi`. If you have a `/sbin/fsck.vfat` on your system, this might allow the system to fix this error automatically on next boot after losing power.

Comment: My hardware system has a UPS. If I use UPS, I need to write a shell script in the background to detect the power signal once per second (because the UPS power supply time is not very long). I am worried that this will affect the performance of the system; If I add a fix to this error in `rcS`, will it have any impact on system stability?

Comment: Running a filesystem check on `/boot/efi` might slightly increase the system start-up time, but should have no impact after the check is complete. But relying on a shell script for detecting the power loss signal does not seem like a good idea. If the power signal can be configured to trigger an interrupt, a real kernel driver could just set up an interrupt handler and then sleep until the interrupt is received. Even if interrupts are not available, doing once-per-second polling in a kernel driver should be much more efficient than doing it in a shell script.